# Daylight Saving Time for selected location and date

Tags: javascript, timezone, momentjs, dst

I need get DST(Daylight Saving Time) true or false to selected date and selected city

I have form with two input fields and one output

First input field: user input city (using google maps places autocomplete )
Second input field: calendar (using datepicker)

Output: user get in selected city and selected date is DST or not, example:
London, 2015/06/22 - DST true
or
Berlin, 2015/11/11 - DST false

I try momentjs: `moment([year, month, day]).isDST()` - not working (only for user location)

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [*timezone*](http://momentjs.com/timezone/) moment.js plugin allows you to do it, as you can read in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24000306/5247200) answer. The problem is that you will need to know on which time-zone that city is located.

To get to know the time-zone for a location on the earth, you can use the [Google Time Zone API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/timezone/intro). Now the problem is that you need to provide the specific Latitude/Longitude pair.

To do so, [you can use Google Maps API](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11149144/5247200).

It is not very straightforward though :)